# Create new column based on for loop

Tags: for-loop

In the code below, I'm taking an xlsx file and determining if a surgery overlapped based on 4 different date/time columns. Everything works fine except for the end of it where I'm trying to do the below which is what i'm trying to do in the last two lines. The new column is based on the results of the for loop, keeping all the columns in the original dataframe which are stated in DfResults.

- Create a new column called "Overlap Status"
- If conflict == True then value in new column is "Overlapped"
- If conflict == False then value in new column is "Did not Overlap"

import pandas as pd

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(r'Directory\File.xlsx')



dfResults = df1.loc[(df1['conflict'] == True),
                 ['LOG ID','Patient MRN',
                  'Providers Name', 'Surgery Date', 'Incision Start', 'Incision Close', 'Sedation Start', 'Case Finish']]

print(dfResults)

#df1.loc[:,'Overlap Status'] = df1.loc[(df1['conflict'] == True), "Overlapped"]
#df1.loc[:,'Overlap Status'] = df1.loc[(df1['conflict'] == False), "Did not Overlap"]
```

**Expected Output:**

| Log ID | Patient MRN | Providers Name | Surgery Date | Incision Start | Incision Close | Sedation Start | Case Finish | Overlap Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | T, GEORGE | 9/2/2021 | 9/2/2021 11:43 AM | 9/2/2021 1:27 PM |  | 9/2/2021 2:14 PM | Overlapped |
| 456 | DEF | T, GEORGE | 9/2/2021 | 9/2/2021 1:46 PM | 9/2/2021 3:20 PM |  | 9/2/2021 3:41 PM | Overlapped |
| 789 | GEF | S, STEVEN | 9/1/2021 | 9/1/2021 9 AM |  |  | 9/1/2021 10 AM | Did not overlap |

Comment: Please post a sample of your data. It can be done much simpler

Comment: Included sample data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.. just had to it with numpy

```
df1['Overlap Status'] = np.where(df1['conflict'] == True, 'Overlapped', 'Did not overlap')
df1.drop(['Start', 'End', 'SedStart', 'conflict'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```